# Html Button click is not working on Firefox

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, firefox, webforms

On my webpage I have a **html button** , It works perfectly on chrome and I have no idea why its **not working on Firefox** . please tell my why its not working..

**Design**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
     <button id="Button1" class="btn btn-green btn-block" onserverclick="SaveIt" runat="server">
      Save <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
     </button>
 </div>
```

**C# Function**

```
protected void SaveIt(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //operations
}
```

How to solve this browser compatibility issue ??

Comment: what message do you get when you open firefox's console and click the button?

Comment: It looks like you're using asp.net, if you're using webforms can you just not use asp:button control instead?

Comment: @Ferus7 no responce from firefox , page is not posting

Comment: @user3739842 for better design sometimes we have to stick with html, right ?

Comment: @Kirk Not at all... the asp:button control will render as a regular html input and you can style as you wish with your css. If you apply the same css classes it will look the same

Comment: @user3739842 as you can see there is a `fa-arrow` inside button , i dont know how to place that inside asp button , anyway thats not the issue here..

Comment: what is the <i> tag ? an image attached to the class?

Comment: try restarting your system, sometimes it will help  :D !!

Comment: @Kirk If you are just using the <i> tag to display an image to the button, you can just apply background-image css to the rendered asp:button instead. Not sure why you have such a problem with using asp controls, you're developing in the asp environment?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your button control to an asp button. It should work then. Like this...

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="SaveIt()" Text="Save" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET WebForms everything that should interact with the server - as in this case, where you handle the click ON the server - needs to be placed within a `form` tag. It is not clear from your post, but I'm assuming you didn't create one in your master page ...

Comment: I have `form ` tag on my master page , !!

Answer (score 0):

Unlike an `asp:button`, the click is handled with javascript (just like a `LinkButton`). In html the button becomes something like this:

```
<button onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$mainContentPane$Button1','')" id="mainContentPane_Button2" class="btn btn-green btn-block">
```

So if it does not work it could be a javascript error present in Firefox but not Chrome. Here some tips

- Test it with a LinkButton
- Check the browser console for javascript errors
- Do you have browser-specific scripts somewhere, if so remove them for testing